# CSS transition opacity only from 0 to 1, or alternative transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a div element in which all my HTML are inserted. I want to create a fade in effect when the content of this div changes. Currently I set the opacity to 0 before inserting something to this div and then set it to 1, so that the effect takes place. The problem with my CSS is that is works for both cases, either for going from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. Is there a way to make it work only when transitioning from 0 to 1; Is there a better alternative for transitioning from one page to another in a single page app?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Imports -->
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="app"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.app
{
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 1s;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

**Javascript**

When the page loads the opacity is set to 1 and the effect takes place:

```
document.getElementById("app").style.opacity='1';
```

The problem occurs when another page is loaded, where the opacity is now set to 0, thus making the transition take effect again.

**Edit**
Updated with better explanation of the problem:

The opacity of the element does not change. What I want for the opacity is only to work when going from 0 -> 1, so that before I insert new content is set to 0 again (thus making the effect taking place, this is the problem) and when all the data have been inserted, a fade in (opacity going from 0 to 1) effect will take place.

Comment: What do you mean by _"when another page is loaded"_?

Comment: So, after setting the `opacity` to `1`, set the `transition` to `none` so the effect will cease.

Comment: _"By loading another page I mean that the whole content of the div changes"_ Why would inserting new HTML into the element cause the `opacity` of the element to change? Do you mean if or when the `window` is reloaded? Can you include the complete JavaScript at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314  The opacity of the element does not change. What I want for the opacity is only to work when going from 0 -> 1, so that before I insert new content is set to 0 again (thus making the effect taking place, this is the problem) and when all the data have been inserted, a fade in (opacity going from 0 to 1) effect will take place.

Comment: Have you considered including that description of the actual problem at the question? _"when another page is loaded"_ is ambiguous.

Comment: @guest271314 Updated the post to include your advice

Comment: @user1798707 The term _"another **page** is loaded"_ is also unclear. What exactly is a "page"? And how is a "page" "loaded" in the actual code? For example is the new HTML inserted into the parent element considered a "page" at https://plnkr.co/edit/GdCszlzlO6yP5rL2Lxj2?p=preview? Have you read the link at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638333/css-transition-opacity-only-from-0-to-1-or-alternative-transition-effect#comment96069040_54638333?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would add a class which is responsible for the transition. If you only add the transition rule *only* within the class, you'll get the one-way transition you're after:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.app').classList.toggle('change');
});
```

```css
.app {
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  opacity:0;
}

.app.change {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad nesciunt adipisci, ab ea deleniti ullam eius alias aperiam, explicabo dolore nihil, ex dolores perferendis. Commodi ipsa dignissimos magni consectetur soluta!</div>

<button>toggle opacity</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add the `transition` property only when you want it to animate. I'll show you how to do it with two classes.

```
.app {
 background-color:#f8f8f8;
 opacity: 0;
}
.app.is-loaded {
 transition: all 1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

...

```
document.getElementById("app").classList.add('is-loaded');
```

Now when you remove that class, the opacity won't have a transition back to `0`.